# Ruby failing to override send method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eventmachine

This is a bit hard to explain, but I seem to be occasionally unable to override the 'send' method in my application.  I'm creating a fairly large application based on EventMachine and sometimes, deep in the bowels of my code, I decide to define a 'send' method in one of my classes.  When I later attempt to use this method, I normally get an exception that looks something like `TypeError: <parameter> is not a symbol`, such as the following (happens to be caused by the required AMQP gem (not mine), but this question is more general):

```
Exception caught: TypeError - #<AMQ::Protocol::MethodFrame:0x000001008434f0 @payload="\x002\x00\x14\x00\x00\x01a\tamq.topic\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00", @channel=1> is not a symbol
/Users/mlartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rflow-component-devel/gems/amq-client-0.7.0.alpha27/lib/amq/client/queue.rb:137:in `bind'
/Users/mlartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rflow-component-devel/gems/amqp-0.8.0.rc12/lib/amqp/queue.rb:282:in `block in bind'
/Users/mlartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rflow-component-devel/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/lib/em/deferrable.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/mlartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rflow-component-devel/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/lib/em/deferrable.rb:47:in `callback'
```

This is the offending line:

```
@connection.send(Protocol::Queue::Bind.encode(@channel.id, @name, exchange_name, routing_key, nowait, arguments))
```

In this particular case, the `@connection` object's class has defined a `send` method that takes in an `AMQ::Protocol::MethodFrame`.  It seems, however, that somehow the default `Object#send` method is getting called (which expects a symbol, hence the exception).

Earlier in development, I had the same issue on one of my custom classes, which was solved by changing the name of my 'send' method to 'send_message'.

So, as this is a bit general, the question is, what sorts of things could interfere with my ability to call a custom-defined `send` method on the object that defined it?

FYI: I'm using Ruby 1.9.2p180 on OSX.

Comment: Is this happening in development only? Is it possible that class reloading is the issue as classes are not cached in development if you are adding methods during execution the class could be reloaded without your newly defined methods?

Comment: I'm not saying I recommend this, but you could `Object.class_eval { undef :send }` to undefine `Object#send`. For the cases you still need it, it's available as `Object#__send__`.

Comment: Steve, I only have development at the moment.  Is there something that I don't understand about Ruby, rvm, bundler that would do class reloading without me knowing it, or would I have to be explicit about that?

Comment: And actually, in playing around, it seems like this could be a `nil` object problem, i.e. if the receiver object is `nil` then it will attempt to execute `Object#send`.  So perhaps its was just my confusion.

Comment: @Michael L. Arts. In the development environment classes are not cached and are reloaded for each request. Within production environments classes are cached so you do not have the overhead of loading all the classes for each request. This is controlled within the environments config files by modifying the value of config.cache_classes

Comment: Steve, Its a straight-up Ruby App, not a Rails app.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommendable to use or override the `send` method. [Object.send](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999) is a very basic method in the Ruby [Kernel Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html). I once got heavy problem when I defined a `Message.send` class, and ended up in using a different name, such as `Message.transmit`. In Ruby on Rails it is a [reserved word](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords).

Comment: About what I thought.  I guess the symptom of this problem is a confusing `TypeError` exception when there is acutally a `nil` object receiver (`nil` recieves the `send`).